# Increasing radial velocity even if radial acceleration is zero

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

In one of the lectures on Mechanics in polar coordinates, my professor gave an example in which he showed that **even if the radial acceleration of a particle is zero it can have an increasing radial velocity** which is quite ambiguous for me. How can that happen !!

I asked him the reason but he didn't give a satisfactory one and so I am here.

***Can someone help me to understand how exactly that happens ?***

## Edit:

I just want to mention that I know the mathematics behind all these polar mechanics but I wanted to know how does the mathematics support that phenomenon. A physically intuitive answer is more appreciated.

Comment: First of all,  are you asking about an ordinary circular motion?

Comment: @Tejas Dahake No .. i didn't mention anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

The situation corresponds to $$a_r = \ddot{r} - r\dot\theta^2 = 0$$ with the most general solution of the form:
$$r = c_1e^{\dot{\theta} t}+c_2e^{-\dot{\theta} t}$$
The radial component of the velocity is $\bf{v}.{e_r}$ $= \dot{r}$, and if we want $\dot{r}$ to be a strictly increasing function of $t$, we require $\ddot{r}>0$ or equivalently $r\dot\theta^2>0$ which is possible for all $r>0$ as long as $\dot{\theta} \ne 0$, because $\dot\theta^2 >0 \ \forall  \ \dot{\theta} \in \mathbb{R} - \text{{0}}$ (supressing units).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the radial velocity is

$$v_r=\frac{dr}{dt}$$

and the radial acceleration

$$a_r=\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}-r\,\dot\phi^2$$

with the conservation of the angular momentum $~\dot\phi=\frac{h}{r^2}~$ and $~a_r=0~$ you obtain :

$$ 
\frac{dv_r}{dt}=\frac{h^2}{r^3}$$

thus
$$v_r(t)=\int \frac{h^2}{r(t)^3}\,dt~~\ne 0$$